# PC will not boot off of any CD to reset password

Tags: windows-xp, boot, passwords

Unfortunately my Dad passed away a little over a week ago, and I have his PC.  I am trying to log onto his computer, but I cannot because I don't have a password.  He changed the password on the administrator account from the default so I can't log with that (it's the account he used anyways, so there is no others, and guest is disabled).  I know there are several methods involving booting off of a CD, but I can't get it to boot off of them.

I just got done rebuilding it to clean out dust and remove the smoke smell, and I put it back together the way it was at first.  I have tried connecting the SATA CD drive to port 1 on the MOBO, and configuring the boot order in the bios, but that doesn't work.  I then tried an IDE drive he had in there, configured for Master and connected to the IDE port, but that didn't boot either.

The boot disks I am trying are Windows 7, Ones made with Active, and a Ubuntu disk, with both the OS ones booting on my PC.  If I disable all other boot devices except the CD drive (so it can't default to anything else), it wants me it insert a bootable medium and press a key.  When I do that, or on initial boot, the drive is active and it pauses before displaying the message as if it is trying to boot off of the disk, but is still unsuccessful.  I can't reset the password if I can't boot off of anything but the hard-drive.  I do have some hard-drives laying around with operating systems on them, so I could try booting off of them, but then I wouldn't know what steps to take to reset the password on the original hard-drive.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked all the BIOS settings?  Changed the boot priority?

Comment: Yes, I have even made the CD drive the ONLY boot device but it still doesn't work.  I also cleared the BIOS nvram in hopes it would reset something that would fix it, but it still didn't.

Comment: Have you tried booting it from a usb/hard drive (external)?  Sorry about the question but I'm just eliminating certain stuff.

Comment: Sounds like the CD drive isn't working properly

Comment: Can you take out the disk and connect it to a different PC?

Comment: I am rather sure it isn't the CD drive because I tried more than 1, and they both had the same problem.  I can't find the option to boot from a flash drive, and I just plugged in two different bootable hard-drives and neither worked.  This thing is just adamant about booting into the original drive.  BTW I am plugging the IDE into the primary slot on the board, but there is also a card with IDE slots (he used it so he could add more hard-drives, don't know why he didn't just use SATA thought).

Comment: I would suggest taking the harddrive out and putting it into another machine running windows, and just using that to take ownership of whatever files you need to access.

Comment: @Darth I will probably end up doing that if I can't figure anything else out soon.

Comment: Another option is to create a bootable Linux USB drive, and boot from that.

Comment: If the CD's also do not read or boot in other systems, than it might be the speed you are burning at.

Comment: @JAKE5469 Sorry to hear about your Dad, my condolences. If you are downloading password cracking ISO files they need to be burned to disc as an "image" not data.

Comment: @Moab thanks for your condolences.  On another note, the boot disks I have were ISOs burnt to the disk using an iso burner, and they do boot on my PC, but not my dads, so I believe it isn't the disks.

Comment: @JAKE6459 if it is XP Home boot into Safe Mode, this is the hidden admin account, and may not have a password set, if you get into safe mode go to control panel and clear the password on the regular user account, reboot normally into that account.

Comment: OK, I finally got it to boot of CD, I couldn't use the SATA one, I had to use two IDE ones on the same IDE cable and it booted off one of them.  It doesn't really make sense why, but it worked.  Wish SATA CD drives would work.  Then I used ophcrack and I am good, and all the data I need to keep is backed up on disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get it to boot, you can use [ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/) to reset the password.